# How to have a backend_model be associated to a Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a Ticker Model -

```py
class Ticker(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.symbol}-{self.company_name}'
```

And

```py
class Model(models.Model):
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(Ticker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test_loss = models.FloatField(null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.ticker.symbol}'
```

I want to add this function to Model -

```py
def predict(self, pred_date):
    return self.backend_model.predict(pred_date)
```

Where -

```py
self.backend_model = LstmModel(self.ticker.symbol)
```

How do I add this `backend_model` to `Model` only once during instantiation?

These are the solutions I have thought of -

1. Have a custom Model Manager.
2. Override `save()` method of Model.
3. Add a `classmethod` to Model

Which one should I use, or if someone can suggest a better way?

Comment: What is `symbol` in `LstmModel(symbol) `? Is it `self.ticker.symbol` from a Model instance perspective?

Comment: @ViggieSmalls Yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, so it might fail here and there. Keep in mind that this should (1) cause your server start to take a while (2) you will have to restart your server to update the registry, among other issues. Use it at your own risk ;)

You can define a registry somewhere in your project like this:

```py
class LstmModelRegistry:
    def __init__(self):
        self._registry = {} 

    def register(self, symbol):
        self._registry[symbol] = LstmModel(symbol)

    def get_service_by_symbol(self, symbol):
        service = self._registry.get(symbol)
        if not service:
            raise Exception('Unknown service')
        return service


lstm_registry = LstmModelRegistry()
```

And then in one of your app configs, you can do something like this:

```py
class SomeAppConfig(AppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        from path.to.lstm.registry import lstm_registry
        from path.to.ticker.model import Ticker

        symbols = list(Ticker.objects.values_list('symbol', flat=True))
        for symbol in symbols:
            lstm_registry.register(symbol)
```

This will load the registry, then build the lstm models by getting all the symbols from the `Ticker` model. You can then define your model like:

```
from path.to.lstm.registry import lstm_registry


class Model(models.Model):
    ...
    def predict(self, pred_date):
        return lstm_registry.get_service_by_symbol(self.ticker.symbol).predict(pred_date)
```

This should in turn just run `predict` without the expensive `LstmModel` load when you serve a request.